# Last row of datagrid (com.inmethod.grid.datagrid) when selected, hangs all JS under Chrome

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, wicket, wicketstuff

When selecting the last row in a datagrid-generated table (with setClickRowToSelect(true)  of course), all javasript on the page hangs. That happens only on chrome (as far as I know). The same thing happens on wicketstuff's official example at http://wicketstuff.org/grid-examples/data-grid/

I would be very grateful for finding any way how to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not grid problem. This issue is related to this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-3820. It works properly in wicket 1.4.18 again.